# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to add new customers to my e commerce database.  I keep getting this error when trying to register a new client.  The browser just shows the preload icon and does not do anything.

This is the error that shows under inspect mode.  Otherwise the background remains white and doesn't load:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `ookxpoll_ukulimamodern`.`tbl_customer`.`cust_b_country` at row 1 in /home/ookxpoll/public_html/ukulimamodernseedlings.co.ke/registration.php:152
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/ookxpoll/public_html/ukulimamodernseedlings.co.ke/registration.php(152): PDOStatement->execute()
> #1 {main}
> thrown in

Surprisingly it works just fine when I use my localhost.  And Yes, I can confirm that my config.php db credentials are correct.

I tried changing the formats in the database for the date and time format from varchar.  I tried setting the default to Current_datetime.  I have tried to exclude the date and time of registration but it still will not update the database.

Here is the code snippet:

```
if($valid == 1) {

        $token = md5(time());
        $cust_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $cust_timestamp = time();

        // saving into the database
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_customer (
                                        cust_name,
                                        cust_cname,
                                        cust_email,
                                        cust_phone,
                                        cust_country,
                                        cust_address,
                                        cust_city,
                                        cust_state,
                                        cust_zip,
                                        cust_b_name,
                                        cust_b_cname,
                                        cust_b_phone,
                                        cust_b_country,
                                        cust_b_address,
                                        cust_b_city,
                                        cust_b_state,
                                        cust_b_zip,
                                        cust_s_name,
                                        cust_s_cname,
                                        cust_s_phone,
                                        cust_s_country,
                                        cust_s_address,
                                        cust_s_city,
                                        cust_s_state,
                                        cust_s_zip,
                                        cust_password,
                                        cust_token,
                                        cust_datetime,
                                        cust_timestamp, 
                                        cust_status      
                                    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement->execute(array(
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_name']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_cname']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_email']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_phone']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_country']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_address']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_city']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_state']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_zip']),
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        md5($_POST['cust_password']),
                                        $token,
                                        $cust_datetime,
                                        $cust_timestamp,
                                        0                                 <!--This is line 152-->
                                    ));

        // Send email for confirmation of the account
        $to = $_POST['cust_email'];
        
        $subject = LANG_VALUE_150;
        $verify_link = BASE_URL.'verify.php?email='.$to.'&token='.$token;
        $message = '
'.LANG_VALUE_151.'<br><br>

<a href="'.$verify_link.'">'.$verify_link.'</a>';

        $headers = "From: noreply@" . BASE_URL . "\r\n" .
                   "Reply-To: noreply@" . BASE_URL . "\r\n" .
                   "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 
                   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . 
                   "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        
        // Sending Email
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        unset($_POST['cust_name']);
        unset($_POST['cust_cname']);
        unset($_POST['cust_email']);
        unset($_POST['cust_phone']);
        unset($_POST['cust_address']);
        unset($_POST['cust_city']);
        unset($_POST['cust_state']);
        unset($_POST['cust_zip']);

        $success_message = LANG_VALUE_152;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're passing an empty string into `cust_b_country`. Country doesn't sound like it should be a date/time, it sounds like it should be a varchar.

Comment: Don't use MD5 for hashing passwords.

Comment: Have a look [password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords) on how to properly store passwords